# Extracting refresh_token from OpenID Connect for Azure billing API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have a headless background job that has to go and fetch a bunch of stuff from azure service management api on a regular basis. This requires an access_token from an authenticated user that has access to the required resources. As it is a background job, the access token needs to be able to be persisted for the app by a different app that handles authentication.

For that, I have created a Web application with .NET Core that uses OpenID Connect to create a user and... what I'm having trouble with is retrieving anything other than the access_token, despite Fiddler clearly showing refresh_token and everything else that comes with it.

What I basically want to do, is give a user with administrative rights the ability to log on, and basically say "Use this account to fetch subscription and billing data", whereby their refresh_token would be persisted and used to renew access_token when that expires.

What I don't want to do is implement my own OAuth flow. I don't really need it - I just want to be able to extract the refresh_token for background job. I've also tried adding "offline_access" to Scopes property on OpenIdConnectOptions, which doesn't seem to change anything...

Is there a better way of having a background service interact (on a fairly permission level) with azure objects like billing API than trying to get a user to authenticate with it? One of my requirements is that I need to be able to enumerate all of the subscriptions associated with the account, which is why I'm trying the authentication route...

E: I think it needs to be a better way of handling background services because refresh_token only lasts a maximum of 90 days and there really shouldn't be a need for someone to keep re-authenticating the app...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK ,ADAL 3 won't expose refresh token , ADAL caches refresh token and will automagically use it whenever you call AcquireToken and the requested token need renewing,please see the explanation from [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/13/adal-3-didnt-return-refresh-tokens-for-5-months-and-nobody-noticed/) .

I would suggest make headless background job run as an application identity, if user's identity is not necessary, use [Client Credentials Grant flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) , you could find code samples from [here](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-code-samples.md)(Server or Daemon Application to Web API section).